# How to place last Bootstrap's row at the bottom of the page's content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and I want to place the last `row` of the `.container` at the bottom of the page's content.

The first thing I've tried was the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .highlight {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .push-to-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container highlight">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row push-to-bottom text-center highlight">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button>Press me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

However, it doesn't work as expected because of the `position: absolute` property -- the last row doesn't know anything about other elements in DOM, so it gets wrong width and positioning.

Well, I changed this code to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .highlight {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .rel {
        position: relative;
      }

      .push-to-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container highlight rel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row push-to-bottom text-center highlight">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button>Press me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

As you see, I've added the `position: relative` property to the `.container` element, so now `width: 100%` do the right job, and our element placed in the `.container` visually. But it still has the following problems:

- It doesn't care about other `row`s, so it can overlap with other rows' content
- It still doesn't placed at the bottom of the page, not the `.container` only

How can I achieve such behavior without hardcoding heights and widths as suggested in other questions related to this problem?

Comment: You want something like this? http://i.imgur.com/hsqh92L.png

Comment: @Preetesh Not only. I also want the last `row` to be at the bottom of the page as well

Comment: In that case, have you tried `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use footer.

```
<footer id="footer" class="footer row">
        <div class="container">
        Your text or DOM here
        </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
display: block;
bottom: 0px;
height: [depends by content]
right: 0%;
left: 0%;
position: fixed !important;
position: absolute;
top: expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+ (document.documentElement.clientHeight? document.documentElement.clientHeight: document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe=document.documentElement.scrollTop? document.documentElement.scrollTop:document. body.scrollTop))+'px');
text-align: center;
visibility: visible;
}
```